Group generated by $G = \langle (5,6,7), (5,6,7,8,9) \rangle$
Let
$$G = \langle \sigma = (1,2,3,4)(5,6,7), \omega = (1,3)(5,6,7,8,9) \rangle \leq S_9$$
Prove that $G$ decomposes as a direct product of two subgroups of $G$ that move disjoint sets of digits. Use this fact to find the order and structure of $G$.

I alredy know that $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $(1, 3)$ generate $D_4$.
But, with $(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)$ I have no clue, I did al congugates between powers of $(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)$ and the powers of $(5, 6, 7)$ but none of them seems to give information about the group they generate.
I have this idea, but I'm not sure it is correct:
$(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)$ and $(5, 6, 7)$ both move $5$ digits from $5$ to $9$, so it is a subgroup  of $A_5$ (both generators are even), so at most it has order $60$, by Cauchy therem if a prime divides the order of thw group, there is a subgroup with that order, but it is impossible that our group have elements with even order because of the generators, so because we know that there are two sobgrouos with order $5$ and $3$ (each one genereted by one of the generators) the order of the wanted group should be $15$.
And that's all I have

Why it should be isomorphic to  $S_5$?

You are right about the permutation group generated by $\sigma = (5\, 6\, 7)$ and $\tau = (5\, 6\, 7\, 8\, 9)$ being a subgroup of $A_5$, but it isn't a subgroup of order $15$. Although these generators have order not divisible by $2$, the subgroup they generate certainly may (and in this case, does) have elements of order $2$.
First, observe that $\langle \sigma, \tau \rangle$ has order divisible by $15$ by Lagrange's theorem. Next, we have $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = (6 \, 7 \, 8)$, so the elements $\sigma$ and $\tau$ don't commute. Then, the order of the subgroup cannot be equal to $15$ (for otherwise, the subgroup would have to be cyclic, but it isn't abelian from the previous computation). We also know that $A_5$ has no subgroups of order $30$ (since such a subgroup would have index $2$, which would make it a normal subgroup, but $A_5$ is simple). This forces the subgroup to have order $60$, making it equal to $A_5$.
Alternatively, just observe that $\sigma$ and $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ generate a subgroup of $A_4$ (by acting on $5, 6, 7, 8$) with $\sigma$ and $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ generating distinct subgroups of order $3$. This forces the subgroup of $A_4$ to be $A_4$ itself. Now, you know that the order of $\langle \sigma, \tau \rangle$ is divisible by $12$ as well as $15$, so it must be divisible by $60$, making it $A_5$.

Thank you very much
